# Not able to find login form anymore on Drupal

Tags: forms, users

We are not able to find the login form anymore on Drupal. We can't find the form on site.com/user/login... We can't find it anywhere.

How can we login?

Comment: are you getting "Access Denied" or page is displaying but form is not diplaying?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a problem of clean urls?

Try site.com/?q=user

Comment: No, not finding anything there. We see only Log in(active tab), Create new account, Reset your password. But we don't see a login form.

Comment: So the page is actually loading?
In that case, if you have access to command line i would try to run: drush uli This will generate a one time login link for you as uid 1 (full admin). Then at least you can debug.

Comment: Okey, thanks! I hope this will work. Let's have a look. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If the login form is not showing in `/user/login` then what you need to do is to switch back to the default (bartik) theme by modifying your database OR using Drush.

See this answer [3 simple steps to recover your site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036200/drupal-7-theme-settings-in-mysql#answer-18038172) OR [Unusable Theme: How to Reset Your Theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/200774)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by clearing the menu cache.

Answer (score 0):

I've given this advice before and it has actually helped a few people. Load /user and delete all css using inspect in the Browser. Sometimes css that works on one page removes a part of another page.